# csh shell script troubleshooting

Tags: linux, shell, csh

i have the following csh shell script thats giving me errors and I'm not quite sure why. it essentially says that ls and cp commands are not found

```
#!/bin/csh
clear

set path="~/SCRAT_SIMs/V6.0/bin/linux/"
echo "Pushing files to: $path" 

ls packages/

cp -r packages/acte_asym     $path 
cp -r packages/acte_hq/      $path
```

when i get rid of the set path then it seems to work. any ideas?

Comment: try replacing the ~ with the absolute address for your home.

Comment: ok i feel like a noob...I guess the variable `path` is conflicting somehow with PATH. i thought the shell keywords were case sensitive. when i change path to something else, the shell script works.

Comment: Well, you did set your `path` variable to a single directory, thereby losing all the stuff that was in it before (especially `/usr/bin` and `/bin`)... There's going to be a lot of commands that can't be found after that... Generally, you want to add to the `path` variable, not completely replace it...

Answer (score 0):

In csh and tcsh, the `$path` shell variable and the `$PATH` environment variable are tied together. `$PATH` (which applies to everything, not just the shell) is a list of directory names separated by `:` characters. `$path` is a csh array variable that mirrors the contents of `$PATH`.

In your case, you just need to pick a different variable name.

If you actually want to manipulate your execution path, you should usually keep the existing contents of `$path` and add new directories to the beginning or to the end. For example:

```
set path = ( ~/bin $path:q )
```

The `:q` suffix avoids problems if some directory in `$PATH` has funny characters like spaces. Note: Don't use double quotes here:

```
set path = ( ~/bin "$path" )
```

That will expand the entire contents of your `$path` to a single string with embedded spaces; `$path:q` keeps it as an array.

[Obligatory link](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot). (I used to write csh scripts myself, but I've found that sh and bash are much better for programming, though tcsh still has a few advantages for interactive use.)

Comment: thanks for the explanation...I'm picking up shell scripting here and there so this helps alot. also thanks for the link...in trying to trouble shoot csh i came across this [link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt) so I will be switching over to bash instead